# Icons are not populating to be selected for Activity Type Options

Tags: wordpress, civicase, activities, activity

Until today I have been able to change or add an icon to an Activity Type.  Now when I click on the icon, the Choose Icon box pops up with a search dialog and the option for no icon but I'm not seeing the list of selectable icons underneath.

After noticing the behavior I have:

- Rebooted the server
- Cleared cache locally (Wordpress and CiviCRM cache) and from Cloudflare.
- Upgraded from CiviCRM 5.29.0 to 5.29.1
- Disabled all extensions and reenabled them.
- Disabled all extensions except for Shoreditch and CiviCase v5.

Example screenshot:
[image]

It may be important to mention that I am using Wordpress with CiviCase and the CiviCase v5 extension.

Any ideas what could be causing this?  It worked perfectly until this morning and I didn't add anything new to the environment.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was caused by an issue with my local disk cache.  Clearing the cache from my browser allowed the icons to be displayed again.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of icon changes in civi over a couple releases and shoreditch might not be up to date with all of them. There were similar reports for "more" dropdown icons. You could try the latest master version of shoreditch.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!  I uninstalled the Shoreditch extension, deleted its directory from the server and installed the latest master version (1.0-beta2).  This did not resolve the issue.  This is working in other implementations of Civi with 5.29 which is strange.  There is something weird going on in this one environment that I can't quite figure out.

Comment: If you open browser dev tools and look on the network tab is it loading the icon list resource?

Comment: Yes, font-awesome.css is being loaded.  The size shows from disk cache.

Comment: This appears to be a local cache issue.  Clearing my machine cache resolved the issue.  Thank you for your assistance!